# Modify Genmodel from source

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf

Is there a way to modify a genmodel (which was created using an EMF ANT Task)programatically? I do not want to touch it anymore by myself after creation.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by modifying it programmatically? If you mean accomodate it with the new elements of the source models, you can use the ecore2genmodel application (not available in Ant); or re-run your existing ant task with the reconcileGenModel="reload" parameter.

If you mean setting the genmodel attributes (e.g. class name conventions, EMF feature generation settings), I recommend setting them manually. There is no harm that way, it is intended to be customized by hand.

Comment: There is considerable harm - how do other developers know which changes they need to make after creating the genmodel? This information is all to easily lost.

Comment: I don't think the created genmodel should be re-generated after manually modified. The regeneration will naturally lose these changes. However, EMF can reconcile the genmodel to add genmodel elements for the non-existent elements, but the older changes will be visible.